# Chat room Activity on iPad mobile web is 17266d ago... for most of my chat rooms

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

[image]

In fact, of these, only Charcoal shows a recent time stamp.

Comment: Wow, you're . . . ancient.

Comment: I am aware of that M.A.R. - I do measure my birthdays in epochs nowadays :-)

Comment: That's not the app, it's the mobile web view. App does not have built in chat support.

Comment: Oh - okay. Thanks for editing the tag. I just made assumptions as it comes up when I clicky in the app :-)

Comment: Is it just on iPad or is it on the mobile view on a desktop too (i.e. is it device or view dependent)?

Comment: Sadly I have no other devices to test it on for the next few hours.

Comment: And... it has fixed itself, so... cacheing?

Comment: I've seen that happen on android a few times.

Comment: The app just has a link, your browser app is set as the default to open such links. :)

Comment: (Lol - yes, I know, I just dislike iPads so much I'm not even going to try to work with them)

Comment: FWIW, 17266 days from yesterday was the Unix epoch.

Comment: @NobodyNana Unix Epoch +1. It's a common practice to set uninitialized variables to zero.