# Weird activity timeout in mobile chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

I noticed weird message about recent activity in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66754/discussion-on-question-by-fil---) on mobile version of chat:

> [image: recent activity]

Chat room has been created today only, so last activity about 47 years ago is completely wrong. Looks like a using of an unitialized variable.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not **2 years** ago, but more than **47 years** ago, when Intel x86 had not been invented.

Comment: @iDebug true, I missread 'd' as 'h'.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek swear is not enough, we need links!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yep... here it is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294583/339911

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a small bug in the code.

According to your question time, the "Last activity" is exactly Jan 1, 1970, which we all know is the Unix Epoch.

It may be a common practice to set unused (uninitialized) values to zero. The bug is likely caused by that practice.